# Access data object properties inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have the following piece of code:

```
const Menus = wp.api.models.Post.extend({
    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'fh/v1/menus/' + path,
});

const menus = new Menus();
console.log(menus);
```

`menus` outputs the following object:
[image]

How would I be able to access the `data: {` object and it's properties? It looks like it's an object inside an object.

When I do `console.log(menus.attribute)` that works fine, but `console.log(menus.attributes.data)` or even `console.log(menus.attributes.success)` just returns a undefined answer.

I tried doing the following:

`console.log(menus.attributes['data']` also with a undefined answer.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try `menus.attributes[0].data`.
It may work. If not work, try to console this on chrome browser and share the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have an async problem here. You can try console.log the result inside a callback function.

For example you can try a similar approach like this :

```
import axios from 'axios';

async function getItems() {
  const response = await axios.get(SOME_URL);
  console.log('done', response);
  return response;
}

getItems().then(items => console.log('items: ', items))
```

Comment: it's inside the wp-api which is the WordPress Backbone.js client, which is using promises, so hmm.

Comment: I just posted a answer Stelios :) - Thanks for helping out!

Comment: You can upvote my answer if it was helpful thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is ever wondering how to access the data, here is how I had this:

```
const Menus = wp.api.models.Post.extend({
    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'fh/v1/menus/' + path,
});
const menus = new Menus();
```

`console.log(menus)` outputted an Object with properties that have other objects.

To access those properties inside the object, do the following:

```
menus.fetch().then(posts => {
   const data = posts.data;
}
```

Now you're able to access your object properties inside the object - I hope this helps.